# Google charts: Unable to open the url of a google chart from ruby file

Tags: ruby, url, google-visualization

I want the google chart url to load by itself when I run the ruby file from terminal. When I open the output link in a browser, I am able to load the chart. What is that I am missing.

require 'gchart'
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'nokogiri' 
    require 'open-uri'

```
pie_chart = Gchart.pie(:data => [20,10,15,5,50], :title => 'SDRuby Fu level', :size => '400x200', :labels => ['matt', 'rob', 'patrick', 'ryan', 'jordan'])

puts "#{pie_chart}"


**Terminal output:**
ruby google_charts.rb
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chd=s:YMSG9&chl=matt|rob|patrick|ryan|jordan&chtt=SDRuby+Fu+level&cht=p&chs=400x200&chxr=0,20,50
```

Answer (score 0):

require 'launchy'

Launchy.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com")

The above gem resolved my question